# Not able to skip a row in Listview

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-listview

I'm trying to skip a row in my list view, based on certain conditions i'm displaying a row in my listview, but there are certain conditions where i need to skip the whole row, but the problem here is that when ever i try to skip it is displaying the previously populated row

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        final DisplayItem di = getItem(position);

        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = inflater.inflate(getCellForDatatype(fd.getDatatype()), null);
        }

     switch(di.getType()){
        case PIC:
            //view code
            break;
        case SOUND:
            //view code
            break;
        default:
            if(di.getDescription().contains("Number")){
            //view code
        }
        break;
        }
   return v
}
```

The problem here is the else part of the final code, i don't want to return any view. I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: You should filter the list instead of changing visibility of the row i think.

Comment: is there any other option except that? @toffor

Comment: Always you can find workarounds but filtering list is cleaner solution. Why don't you want to filter list ?

Comment: Yes filtering worked for me, really hoped for a better solution, but this works for now, Thank you @toffor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can't do this, the only way i found to do this is to send the desired List to the adapter, that means perform any operation which is necessary to remove the item you want and then send the list.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is return the view, but the set visibility to GONE in the else part before returning the view

```
v.setVisibility(View.GONE)
```

Comment: That makes the whole row blank, it gives a blank view. i don't want that, i want the row to be skipped

Comment: then filter your list which you are using in adapter, after filtering out elements, call notifyDataSetChanged(), it'll redraw the list.